# Google index duplicate secure http of the subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-analytics, sitemap, robots.txt

We have two sub domains on single domain like

```
1) example.com (rails app)
2) blog.example.com (wordpress)
3) sendy.example.com (sendy mailer)
```

where (1) is domain, (2),(3) is sub domain.

We put ssl for example.com.
Now, google indexes duplicate url like (https : //blog.example.com/ios, https : //sendy.example.com/ios) same content in https: //example.com/ios .
if i put http: //blog.example.com or sendy.example.com, it 'll be properly redirected.

my robots.txt file in example.com:

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
#
# To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
# User-agent: *
# Disallow: /
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Now , google indexes like https ://example.com/ios, https ://blog.example.com/ios have same content. How to fix these duplicate index.?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thank you . How to remove the duplicate indexed url for google search.? Is there anything wrong in robots.txt. After I modified the robots.txt file from Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml to Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml this would happened.

Comment: if you want to block the Googlebot you would have to uncomment the user agent and disallow lines in robots.txt. Everything that starts with a hashmark # is a comment and will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canonical links, unless it is a redirection implementation issue. If so, fix that first.